# C# floating point value round to two decimals

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, double

I have a value which is like this in C#:

```
14.995
```

I have tried storing the value inside these variables:

```
double Number;
float Number;
```

Both values seem to round up this number to 15 .. However, instead of 15... I'd like the number to be rounded to the exactly 14.99 :/

```
Number= Math.Round(amount * (1 - calcPerc),2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);\
```

The output is always 15... Is there some way to round this to 14.99 instead of 15 ?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What are `amount` and `calcPerc` (values and data types)? Please give us a [mre]

Comment: @HimBromBeere Not sure that's the right dupe, I'm more likely to believe this is converting to integer, but since OP isn't talking...

Comment: Note that `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` means that when you have to round .5, it rounds it *away from zero*: .5 -> 1 // -.5 -> -1. You might prefer `MidpointRounding.ToZero` instead or check which option fits your needs [MidpointRounding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to truncate everything after the 2nd decimal place

```
decimal calcPerc = 14.995m;
decimal result = Math.Truncate(calcPerc * 100) / 100m; // 14.99
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/eMtqKb

Comment: I see no point why this should be invalid. Any comment on this down vote?

Comment: Not me, but I assume you got downvoted for **assuming** OP's needs

Comment: Since `15` is the correct result of rounding `14.995`, that's the only logical guess

Comment: What about `MidpointRounding.ToZero`? (which is different from truncating)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

decimal Number= 14.995;

Math.Floor(Number* 100) / 100;

Comment: `Math.Floor` fails at negative numbers https://dotnetfiddle.net/OfxL75

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
double n = 14.995;
double newNum  = Math.Floor(n * Math.Pow(10, 2)) / Math.Pow(10, 2);
```

output is `14.99`

Comment: Any reason to use `Math.Pow(10, 2)` and not `100`?

Comment: @Rafalon because it takes value and raise the value to specified power.. read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I know how Math.Pow works, I just wonder why you have to perform this where you can simply write `100`

Comment: @Rafalon Technically, it's the same as writing `100d`, but yes, you're right.

Comment: `Math.Floor` fails at negative numbers https://dotnetfiddle.net/OfxL75